# ng-grid infinite scroll - ngGridEventScroll emited twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I try to implement infinite scrolling grid based on ngGridEventScroll event. But I have it emited twice every time I scroll to the bottom of grid.
Here's my code for update data ($scope.mydata is used as source for grid):

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function () {
    chunkStart += chunkSize;
    $http.get('/api/mydata/' + chunkStart + '/' + chunkSize)
          .success(function(mydata) {
                $scope.mydata = $scope.mydata.concat(mydata);
           });
});
```

Where's my mistake, can you give me any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, here's my solution:

```
$scope.load = true;
$scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function() {
  if ($scope.load) {
    $scope.load = false;
    $http.get('your/url/here')
            .success(function(data) {
              //operations here
              $timeout(function() {
                //or here
                $scope.load = true;
              });
            });
  }
});
```

I used `$scope.load` flag to indicate when to load data and angular `$timeout()` function fix time-related issues.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, but I had to add a small delay for my `$timeout`, e.g. 250